# Why does "data[data==""]" give me NAs and "" together?

Tags: r

My data is a vector and mMy code is the following:

`data[data==""]`

and it results in following output:

`[1] NA NA NA "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA`

I would think it would have ended up only with NAs or ""s but it gives all together.

Comment: Look at the output of `c("",NA) == ""` . This will give you a clue although not knowing if your `data` is a vector, data frame or something else it's hard to be more specific.

Comment: Try using `data[data %in% "", ]` and see if it's any better.

Comment: Logical in indices return `NA` whenever they are `NA`, the correct way is `data[which(data=="")]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either do it with `%in%`, as suggested by others, or in `dplyr` with `filter`:

```
data[data %in% ""]
[1] "" "" "" "" ""

library(dplyr)
data.frame(data) %>%
   filter(data == "")
  data
1     
2     
3     
4     
5
```

Data:

```
data <- c(NA, NA, NA, "", "", "", NA, NA, "", "", NA, NA)
```